# while using Tiny mce pages take for ever to load

Tags: tinymce, pageload

I have a few forms that use tiny mce. I have noticed recently that the page takes for ever to load (over 2 minutes), as soon as I comment out the text area that uses tiny mce the page loads just fine (under 5 seconds). I have no clue what is going on since it was working just fine in my local machine until last week. I'm using apache2, php 5, mysql and xajax.

I have been using xdebug to find out what is wrong and all the code finishes running in the server side, but the browser keeps waiting for the page to finish loading, making the navigation and the form impossible to use.

Any leads on what could be going on will be of great help.

Comment: Are you timing after everything has been downloaded, or do you include the time to get all the files that tinyMCE require?

Comment: that is the total time to generate and load the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you taken a look at Firebug on the Net tab to see wether some file is being loaded too long?